# mysql, php, how to compare numbers

Tags: php, mysql

i have a database: `database` with a table: `table` and some fields:

```
id  fname       dphone      count_pic   dup_id  

6055903 Karla       5126xxx798  1       57  
6173767 Aaliyah     4082xxx534  4       39  
5611411 Aaliyah     4082xxx534  15      39  
5611211 Aaliyah     4082xxx534  18      39  
4234798 Abby        3057xxx974  31      16  
6166691 Walter      6178xxx280  1       74  
3375576 Walter      6178xxx280  17      74
```

what i am trying to do is to select the fields that have the smallest `count_pic` and the ones that have the bigger `count_pic` and that have the same `dup_id`

any ideas how to do this in mysql?

thanks.

Comment: How do you want the results to come out? Do you want one row for each `dup_id`? or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this query you'll select the smallest and the biggest values of `count_pic` for every `dup_id`

```
  SELECT MIN(count_pic) AS minpic,
         MAX(count_pic) AS maxpic,
         dup_id
    FROM `table`
GROUP BY dup_id
```

If you also need corresponding rows, then you could use something like

```
    SELECT *
      FROM `table` t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(count_pic) AS minpic,
                   MAX(count_pic) AS maxpic,
                   dup_id
              FROM `table`
          GROUP BY dup_id) t2 ON t1.dup_id = t2.dup_id
                             AND (t1.count_pic = minpic
                               OR t1.count_pic = maxpic)
```

Comment: hey, what if i want to also add `WHERE t1.fname = t2.fname`. I've been  trying to do this for a while now with no result. I would appreciate it. thanks